# "Trailing data" error when trying to update a record with updateOrCreate method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, datetime

Laravel automatically sets the updated_at and created_at columns fine when I first create a record, but when I go to update the record it gives me a "trailing data" error which I guess has something to do with those 2 fields.

I've tried inserting the updated_at field manually but that doesn't work.

Here is the updateOrCreate code.

```
$pixel = array(
  'player' => $player,
  'x' => $x,
  'z'=> $z,
  'color' => $color,
  'material' => $material
);

Pixel::updateOrCreate(['x' => $x,'z' => $z],$pixel);
```

It should be noted I have a unqiue composite index on the "x" and "z" fields.

Here is the Pixel model.

```
class Pixel extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'pixels';

    protected $fillable = [
       'player','x','z','color','material'
    ];

}
```

This is what the table looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6TB3.png

Here is the full error message.

```
/home/forge/default/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php

            // Prepend mock datetime only if the format does not contain non escaped unix epoch reset flag.
            if (!preg_match("/{$nonEscaped}[!|]/", $format)) {
                $format = static::MOCK_DATETIME_FORMAT.' '.$format;
                $time = ($mock instanceof self ? $mock->rawFormat(static::MOCK_DATETIME_FORMAT) : $mock->format(static::MOCK_DATETIME_FORMAT)).' '.$time;
            }

            // Regenerate date from the modified format to base result on the mocked instance instead of now.
            $date = self::createFromFormatAndTimezone($format, $time, $tz);
        }

        if ($date instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
            $instance = static::instance($date);
            $instance::setLastErrors($lastErrors);

            return $instance;
        }

        if (static::isStrictModeEnabled()) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $lastErrors['errors']));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Create a Carbon instance from a specific format.
     *
     * @param string                          $format Datetime format
     * @param string                          $time
     * @param \DateTimeZone|string|false|null $tz
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     *
     * @return static|false
     */
    public static function createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz = null)
    {
        $function = static::$createFromFormatFunction;

Arguments
"Trailing data"
```

Comment: Carbon doesn't like the milliseconds in your database's DateTime. You'll have to modify your model to take that into account, most likely. This might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/microseconds-with-laravels-timestamp

Comment: @aynber Thanks you actually did help me. I didn't realize that you didn't have to give an argument when creating the datetime() field in the database. I just removed the milliseconds from the field and now it works!